# Soap server port not visible to client

Tags: server, firewall

My soap server running on port 44485. Following is the netstat command output after start the server.

```
$ netstat -ant | grep 44485
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44485           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I can access port 80 from internet but, I can't access 44485 port from internet.

I enable access port with following command

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 44485 -j ACCEPT
```

Please anyone help me to access the server port from internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `iptables` command

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport XXXXX -j ACCEPT
```

or `UFW`

```
sudo ufw allow XXXXX
```

XXXXX - represent your port.

You service listen on port `44485` whay you use in `iptables` port `50605`?

Edit 1 - full `iptables` setup

```
#################################################
# clear existing chains
#################################################

/etc/init.d/iptables stop

iptables --flush
iptables --delete-chain

#################################################
# allow loopback
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# allow all ICMP
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# allow established connections
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# allow public services
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 44485 -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# deny all
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

#################################################
# default policies
#################################################

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

#################################################
# save the new policy
#################################################

service iptables save
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i have use only 44485 port. I have edited the question with correct port. It is a question writing mistake, I'm sorry about it.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, I have try it and issue command 'iptable-save' and restart my server. But it didn't work.

Comment: If is your server on public ip should be work. If you have private ip, behind router, you also must do port fw on router. Try to disable firewall, just for test.

Comment: I post full `iptables` setup like edit 1 in my answer